# OutOfMemoryError on OpenShift

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

I have a Tomcat Java application running on OpenShift (1 small gear) that consists of two main parts: A cron job that runs every minute, parses information from the web and saves it into a MongoDB database, and some servlets to access that data.
After deploying the app, it runs fine, but sooner or later the server will stop and I cannot access the servlets anymore (the HTTP request takes very long, and if it finishes, it returns a `Proxy Error`). I can only force stop the app using the `rhc` command line and restart it.

When I look at the `jbossews.log` file, I see multiple occurences of this error:

```
Exception in thread "http-bio-127.5.35.129-8080-Acceptor-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
unable to create new native thread
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this error without needing to upgrade to a larger gear with more memory?

Comment: increse size of heap memory by adding VM arguments to your server

Comment: @NiravPrajapati Where do I need to set those VM arguments for an OpenShift project? In the `catalina.properties`file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your description I can understand that some memory leak issue is their with your app . That may be because that you are not stooping your threads.

Sometimes what happen is thread will not stop automatically then we need to stop the thread explicitly.

Comment: I don't create any extra threads in the app. I only have the `HttpServlet`s and the cron job (which runs `wget` to start one of the servlets)

Comment: I think I found the problem, see my comment on the other answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, itss not a memory problem, but OS resource problem. You are running out of native threads, max threads your JVM can have.

You can increase it by this way

```
ulimit -s newvalue
```

Comment: When I only type `ulimit` on the Openshift server (via SSH), it returns `unlimited`, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Also after running ulimit -s unlimited, the problem persists.

Comment: If you can not increase that, then it leaves only option to check code to find out why it's creating many threads.

Comment: Ah, I found the error in the code. It wasn't closing the connections to the MongoDB database after opening them so that was generating many threads. I changed that and it seems to run well now.

Comment: Hm. That seems to only have been part of the problem.  It takes longer now, but it still stops working after some time. I'll inspect the code again later.

Comment: Sorry, false alarm. I forgot the closing of the DB connection on one single place where I used it.